# Convert Java String to CLOB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob

I have the following table:
[image]

The problem is that when I try to use JDBC to insert a String to this field I always get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 6019
```

what should I do now?

The java code to generate the INSERT is the following:

```
Connection conn2 = null;
   if(connection==null||connection.isClosed())
   {
    System.out.println("Connection is null");
    conn2 = connectDB();
   }
   //REPLACE is non-standard SQL from MySQL, it's counter part of INSERT IGNORE
   String sql = ""; 
   sql = "INSERT INTO TEST."+tablename+" ("+fields+") VALUES ("+fields.replaceAll("[^,]+", "?")+")";

   System.out.println("SQL: "+sql);
   PreparedStatement pstmt =  conn2.prepareStatement(sql);

   // start parsing
   int event = r.getEventType();
   while (true) {
    // for each wanted element 
    if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT
      && r.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) {
     System.out.println("Table : "+tablename+" / Row : "+rowCount );
     if (attributeCount == 0)
      attributeCount = r.getAttributeCount();


     //put each parameter to SQL
     int f=1;
     for (String field : fieldsArray){
    String value = r.getAttributeValue("",field);
    if("body".equalsIgnoreCase(field) && value != null) {
         pstmt.setCharacterStream(f++, new CharArrayReader(value.toCharArray()), value.length());
    } else {
         pstmt.setString(f++, value);
    }
 }

     pstmt.addBatch();
     rowCount++;

     if(rowCount%rowspercommit==0){
      System.out.println("Importing at row "+rowCount+" ... ");
      pstmt.executeBatch();
      conn2.commit();
     }
    } // end for each row.
```

Not sure how the CREATE TABLE is, as someone did that for me

With the current code above, I am now getting this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBData.clearItem(DBData.java:431)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl.clearItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:3528)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.checkBindTypes(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3271)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStreamItem(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1178)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3539)
    at XMLDumpImporter.importXMLFile(XMLDumpImporter.java:179)
    at XMLDumpImporter.importXMLFolder(XMLDumpImporter.java:117)
    at XMLDumpImporter.main(XMLDumpImporter.java:48)
```

at line:

```
if("body".equalsIgnoreCase(field) && value != null) {
             pstmt.setCharacterStream(f++, new CharArrayReader(value.toCharArray()), value.length());
```

Which made no total sense as what could possibly be null

Comment: Can you show the insert statement and perhaps the create table statement? And the Java code you use to set the value of the clob?

Comment: edited my question above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are using `setString` instead of `setCharacterStream` to set value of the clob. If you are using `setString` then the driver probably converts the value to `varchar2` which has size limit of 4000 characters.

Hackety hack:

```
int fieldIndex = 0;
for(String fieldName : fieldsArray) {
   String value = r.getAttributeValue("",field);
   if(value != null && "body".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
     pstmt.setCharacterStream(++fieldIndex, new StringReader(value), value.length());
   } else {
     pstmt.setString(++fieldIndex, value);
   }
}
```

Relevant documentation:

- [setCharacterStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setCharacterStream%28int,%20java.io.Reader%29) or [setClob](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob%28int,%20java.io.Reader%29) or [setAsciiStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29)
- [StringReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)
- [CharArrayReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayReader.html)
- [ByteArrayInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

Comment: well could you use setCharacterStream when you have a String? I modified my code above, how should I use setCharacterStream?

Comment: @EquinoX - if you have the content in a `String` already you can wrap the `String` into a `CharArrayReader` or a `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: sometimes it gives me the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException:  if("body".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
     pstmt.setCharacterStream(fieldName, new CharArrayReader(value.toCharArray()), value.length());
   }

Comment: check for nullity of the value and proceed as fit

Comment: I actually did check if value == null and it never hit there... weird.. I can't figure out where this null is from

Comment: no it's not, I updated my code using your code on my original post

Comment: and I think the way you initialize setCharacterStream is wrong, the first argument is an int

Comment: figured out that it was some particular value of String value that made this crash.. wonder what that is... because on the row that crashes if I change the value of that string to something else, it worked perfectly fine

Comment: You're of course right about the setCharacterStream parametrs. I've been using wrappers over jdbc for too long it seems :)

Comment: do you have any clue why it generates a NULLPointerException for certain type of strings? In the example above, for certain values of the String variable value

Comment: Can you determine what values have caused the NullPointerException? It's easier to reason the cause when I know the values. Maybe you can use a batch size of 1 while debugging.

Comment: I just figured out the problem, which is weird... the String value has various lengths.. the one that gives me the NullPointerException has a length of 6000 or more... wonder why it failed for a String of length that size and why when it fails it gives NullPointerException... any idea? Those strings with length less than approximately 3000 worked out fine

Comment: Would you mind doing the following test: Run the code without using batching at all. Just `pstmt.execute`. If the code executes ok, then you could check what version of ojdbc you have. There might be some bugs in the older versions.